# How should I call my intermediate table that links albums and album_images in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Up until now, If I had a table called tags and table called images, I'd call the intermediate table `tag_image`, however, I feel like I shouldn't be naming a table `album_album_image`.

The table album_images is called like that because of my AlbumImage model and because it contains all the images uploaded in albums.

Comment: Just call `album_images` - `images`. If you have more models that would need to be related to generic table (name) like `images` make `Image.php` morph model with `images` as morph table. In that case you can follow good db layer design but also known naming convention i.e. `album_images`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could handle this but the simplest solution is to just give the intermediate table a custom name and then specify that table name in your relationship definitions. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

AlbumImage Model

```
class AlbumImage extends Model{
    public funtion albums(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Album::class, 'whatever_table_name_you_want')
    }
}
```

Album Model

```
class Album extends Model{
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AlbumImage::class, 'whatever_table_name_you_want')
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

For the sake of discussion, I'll include a more complex solution. If you don't mind updating table names and refactoring some code, you could rename `AlbumImage` to just `Image`, change it's table name to `images`, give it a polymorphic many-to-many relationship to `Album`, and make the join table name something like `image_assignment`. Then, you could assign images to other models like say `User`, `Track`, `Account`, `Post`, `Comment`, etc. and use just one table to manage the relationships between `Image` and all the other classes. The join table would look somenting like:

```
image_id | image_assignment_id | image_assignment_type
------------------------------------------------------
   1     |          1          | App\Album
   2     |          1          | App\Album
   2     |          2          | App\Album
   3     |          1          | App\User
   4     |          5          | App\Post
```

Your relationship definition would be something like:

```
class Album extends Model{

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Image::class, 'image_assignment');
    }
}
```

Your Image model with definitions for each class it has a polymorphic relationship to

```
class Image extends Model
    public function albums(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Album::class, 'image_assignment');
    }
    public function posts(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'image_assignment');
    }
    public function users(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'image_assignment');
    }
}
```

It sounds complex, but is not very hard to implement if you plan to/decide to have images for multiple classes. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

**Update 2**:

Given that the poster has stated there is already an `Image` class and `images` table with data that relates to images uploaded by users, some data normalization may be necessary.

An example of how the `images` table could look would be:

```
id |     path     | uploader_id 
---------------------------------
1  | "some/path"  |     1       |         
2  | "other/path" |     4       |      
3  | "stuff/"     |    null     |      
4  | "things/"    |     7       |
```

A hypothetical "meta_data" table would look like

```
id |      name    |    description      |   image_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | "fancy name" | "fancy description" |     2     |
```

which would support a one-to-one relationship between an Image and it's MetaData. You can leave the `uploader_id` `null` if your album images are provided via some api rather than user submitted.

Comment: @Tpojka i noticed your comment after i had submitted my update :)

Comment: The problem is that I also have a model called Image and a table called images. The images in that table are meant to be random images which the users could upload. They have name, description, uploader_id, etc, whereas my album_images table should just contain the ids of the images and the path to the image. The album will have the information about what kind of images it contains. I cannot put the album images in the images table because they do not have stuff like name and description.

Comment: Then go with the first option. Otherwise, you absolutely could move the `album_images` to the `images` table. Just leave the fields that you don't have any data for null. Or, if that bothers you, you can normalize the `name` and `description` fields and put them into a seperate table and add a foreign key to each `image` that points to it's "MetaData". Not all images may have that data, but at least you wouldn't have a bunch of null values on your table. I'm not saying you have to do it this way, but the way you described you're doing it sounds messy and not very DRY.

Comment: @Bobimaru I updated my answer. Does that make sense? Again, you may have time constraints or other issues with migrating your data from `album_images` to `images` that prevent you from refactoring your current db and models that much, but it's possible. Like I said though, the first option I gave is acceptable and will allow you to name the join whatever you want it to be.

Comment: I still vote for one table called `images` normalized in a way to be acceptable to both (many) models. In other hand, if you have working DB layout that fulfill your application needs, name tables what ever you want and set it in model as protected property. You have example of that in docs, check [_Table Name_](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models) section.

Comment: @Bobimaru do either of these options answer your question or work for you? If not, why? Glad to provide another update to my answer.